# How to access state from one child component to another child component using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to set state in one child component and access it in another child component using react and typescript.

What I am trying to do?

In component child1 I set `isDialogOpen` state and I need to access it in child2 component.

Below is how the structure is,

```
function Main() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/page1"
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <Layout>
                                <React.Suspense fallback={<PlaceHolder></>}>
                                    <child1 {...routeProps} />
                                </React.Suspense>
                            </Layout>
                        )}
                    />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/page2"
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <Layout>
                                <Child2 {...routeProps} />
                            </Layout>
                        )}
                    />
                    //many other components rendered apart from child1 and child2
                </Switch>
            </React>
        </Wrapper>
    ) 
}


function Child1() {
    return (
        <UploadButton/>
    );  
}

type Props = RouteComponentProps<{ itemId: string; productId: string }>;

function UploadButton({ match }: Props) { //here i set the state isDialogOpen
    const [isDialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handle_click = () => {
        setDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handle_click}/>

            {isDialogOpen && (
                <UploadForm/>
            )}
        </>
    );
}


function Child2() {
    return (
        <UserButton/>
    );
}

function UserButton() {
    return (
        <Icon/>
    );
}
```

Here in the Main component, I am rendering child1 and child2 components.
UploadButton component is where `isDialogOpen` state is set.

Now when the `isDialogOpen` is true I want the Icon in UserButton component to be rendered.

Now the question is to access isDialogOpen state in the UserButton component I have to define a function to set the state in the main component and pass it to child1 -> UploadButton, and pass the state to the child2 component -> UserButton

As I want to pass the state so many levels the other solution could be to use context API.

So I have tried like below,

```
interface DialogCtxState {
    isDialogOpen: boolean;
    setIsDialogOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const initialDialogState: DialogCtxState = {
    isDialogOpen: false,
    setIsDialogOpen: () => {},
};

export const LoadingContext = React.createContext<DialogCtxState>(
    initialDialogState
);

export const DialogContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    return (
        <DialogContext.Provider
            value={{
                isDialogOpen,
                setIsDialogOpen,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </DialogContext.Provider>
    );
}

//wrap contextprovider for main
function Main() {
    return (
        <DialogContextProvider>
            <Wrapper>
                <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/page1"
                            render={routeProps => (
                                <Layout>
                                    <React.Suspense fallback={<PlaceHolder></>}>
                                        <child1 {...routeProps} />
                                    </React.Suspense>
                                </Layout>
                            )}
                        />
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/page2"
                            render={routeProps => (
                                <Layout>
                                    <Child2 {...routeProps} />
                                </Layout>
                            )}
                        />
                        //many other components rendered apart from child1 and child2
                    </Switch>
                </React>
            </Wrapper>
        </DialogContextProvider>
    ) 
}

//set the isDialogOpen in UploadButton as below
function UploadButton({ match }: Props) { 
    const { isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen } = React.useContext(LoadingContext);

    const handle_click = () => {
        setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handle_click}/>

            {isDialogOpen && (
                <UploadForm/>
            )}
        </>
    );
}

function UserButton() {
    const { isDialogOpen } = React.useContext(LoadingContext);
    return (
        {isDialogOpen && <Icon/>}
    );
}
```

this works, but I don't want to wrap the DialogContextProvider around all child components of main. instead, I want the context to be used only in UploadButton, UploadForm and UserButton Components only.

How can I do this? Also, I have many other `contextproviders` wrapped in main. it kind of looks clumsy.

How can I do this other way? Or could someone help me with some better solution thanks.